# Visual Studio debugger doesn't stop on breakpoints

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.android

From time to time I see that debugger doesn't honor breakpoints at all, mostly when there are threads involved. Is this a known problem? If not I'll try to create a repro.

Comment: No such thing has been reported.

Answer (score 2):

FYI a locked MDB file is causing this behaviour. Filled a bug report:
https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=5608

Answer (score 1):

I guess that your IDE is just not attached to those process which works at the moment when you see no stop on breakpoints. Look at this [Walkthrough: Debugging a Multithreaded Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb157784.aspx) to see how to do that safely.

Hope that helps,

Comment: Congrats for partially correct answer :-), meanwhile I've found the cause of this.